# Getting "The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly" in AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-core-2.1

I am implementing a file upload in ASP.Net core.
Everything works fine when testing locally on Windows but when I deploy my code on AWS Lambda, I am getting

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly.
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ReferenceReadStream.VerifyPosition()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ReferenceReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)"

My code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Store([FromForm] MyFiles files)
{
    var stream1 = files.File1.OpenReadStream();
    var stream2 = files.File2.OpenReadStream();
    string result;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream1.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        result= GetCrcForFile(ms);
    }
}

public class MyFiles
{
    public IFormFile File1 { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File2 { get; set; }
}

public string GetCrcForFile(Stream result)
{
    uint crc = 0;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        result.CopyTo(ms);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        crc = Crc32Algorithm.Compute(bytes);
        return crc.ToString("X");
    }
}
```

The exception happens on line `result.CopyTo(ms);`

I am not sure if it is .Net Core behaving differently on Linux environment or AWS Lambda issue or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's `ms.Position = 0` which throws that exception? The setter for `MemoryStream.Position` doesn't physically have the code that would throw that exception. Can we have the full exception type and stack trace?

Comment: This looks similar to the issue you're facing: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1116 but only if you call `files.File2.OpenReadStream` at some point. Have you posted your actual code, or have simplified it?

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, I have updated the question, logs were a little bit misleading

Comment: @KevinGosse, yes I have simplified it, updated to add files.File2.OpenReadStream in the correct position.

Comment: As the GitHub issue linked by @KevinGosse says, I think you need to 1) open stream1, 2) copy to a MemoryStream, 3) Dispose stream1, 4) open stream2. It seems you can't have two such streams open at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated [in this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1116), depending on what kind of server you're using, you cannot access the file streams in just any order. You need to open and process the files in sequential order, or you'll receive this "The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly" exception.

Therefore, make sure to:

- Call `OpenReadStream` on `File1`, then fully process the contents of the file
- Only then, call `OpenReadStream` on `File2`, and so on

Comment: Could you provide more detail? In the link you post do not mention any about server kind

Comment: @MichaelMao Well, the link above clearly states that it happens with TestServer (in-memory) but not with Kestrel

Comment: You are right, but I can't find any list about support or not support