# Only the last file is uploaded (Azure Blob)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I uploading the collection of files to blob as parallel (IFormFiles in C#).

I using semaphore and TPL to parallel uploading. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files))

But all files except the last are uploaded only at 64 Kb. The latest file is fully uploaded.

I don't know why chunk size 4Mb ignored and used 64Kb and why uploads only 1 chunk default size.

Here is a code:

```
public static async Task UploadBulkAsync(string storageConnectionString, string containerName, Dictionary<string, IFormFile> blobNameToFile)
    {
        var completed = 0;
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(AppGlobalSettings.BulkUploadAzureBlobThreadCount, AppGlobalSettings.BulkUploadAzureBlobThreadCount);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        var options = new BlobRequestOptions
        {
            ParallelOperationThreadCount = 20
        };

        var blobContainer = await GetContainerAsync(storageConnectionString, containerName);
        await blobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions() { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

        foreach (var one in blobNameToFile)
        {
            var name = one.Key;
            var file = one.Value;

            var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

            await semaphore.WaitAsync();

            tasks.Add(blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), null, options, null).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                semaphore.Release();
                Interlocked.Increment(ref completed);
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell what is contained in `blocks` variable here `var blocks = GetFileBlocks(file);`?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the collection of IFormFile objects. You cannot open multiple IFormFile streams in the same request processing. They need to be processed sequentially.

link: [Getting "The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly" in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674322/getting-the-inner-stream-position-has-changed-unexpectedly-in-aws-lambda)