# The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to upload two files from Azure Function which I have received through multipart/form-data

var formdata = await reqstring.ReadFormAsync();

var frontfile = reqstring.Form.Files["frontfile"];

var backfile =  reqstring.Form.Files["backfile"];

var client_KYC_OCR = new RestClient(options);
var request_KYC_OCR = new RestRequest(_KYC_Kart_URL + "/api/passport/extraction", Method.Get);

```
                    request_KYC_OCR.AddHeader("x-api-key", _KYC_Kart_Token);
                    request_KYC_OCR.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                    request_KYC_OCR.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
                    request_KYC_OCR.AddFile("front", getFile: frontfile.OpenReadStream, frontfile.FileName, frontfile.ContentType);
                    request_KYC_OCR.AddFile("back", getFile: backfile.OpenReadStream, backfile.FileName, backfile.ContentType);
                    

                    RestResponse response_KYC_OCR = await client_KYC_OCR.ExecuteAsync(request_KYC_OCR);
```

But I am getting the ERROR:

"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.VerifyPosition()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer,
Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination,
Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.SerializeToStreamAsyncCore(Stream stream, TransportContext context,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore(ValueTask copyTask)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
HttpContentWriteStream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
End of inner exception stack trace   at RestSharp.RestClient.ThrowIfError(RestResponse response)
at RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteAsync(RestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Urbanmoney_AZ.Functions.KYC_Update.Run(HttpRequestMessage req, HttpRequest reqstring, ILogger log)

I tried googling the same but not found any Eact Solution for the same

Can anyone help me out please

Comment: Can you report back if you're facing the same issue if you use the synchronous Execute method instead of ExecuteAsync?

Answer (score 0):

- As 'per this [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1116) Issue "The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly" exception may cause because of the sequential order. Try opening and processing files in sequential order.
- Also as suggested by [Bandook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9276081/bandook) try synchronous execution method rather than execute Async method
- for further details check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674833) thread.